# String function does not return

Tags: c++, class, oop

I've written a piece of code. There's a class Rational with numerator and denominator as its private members. Now there is a method toString() which should return the rational number as a string ("numerator/denominator"). For unknown reasons to me, it does not return anything. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Rational {
    long int n, d;
public:
    Rational(long int n, long int d) {
        this->n = n;
        this->d = d;
    }
    bool equals();
    int compareTo();
    std::string toString() {
        string resN, resD;
        string str;
        ostringstream convertN, convertD;
        convertN << this->n;
        convertD << this->d;
        resN = convertN.str();
        resD = convertD.str();

        str = resN + "/" + resD;
        return str;
    }
};

int main() {
    Rational rat(2, 3);
    rat.toString();

    return 0;
}
```

First I thought something with the conversion algorithm was wrong, and I tried returning anything, but still nothing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It does return the string and then throws it away. (BTW Bill Hicks was a good comedian and as he is dead I do not think you are him)

Comment: Less verbose option:  `string toString() { ostringstream s; s << n << '/' << d; return s.str();}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output the string, use `cout << rat.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

It does return something, you're just not using the value that it returns. I know in languages like MATLAB, it can print out the result. Here, you have to do that yourself. Try this:

```
int main() {
    Rational rat(2, 3);
    std::string theString = rat.toString();
    cout << "The result is: " << theString << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```